# Is it possible that processor heating not because of cooling system fault?

Tags: cpu, cooling, cpu-cooler, thermal-paste

If laptop continue heating after you changed thermal compound does it necessarily means that it's something to do with thermal compound (bad quality or wrong applied). Taking into account the fact that the other part of cooling system is fine. Can be something wrong with CPU itself ?

Comment: Unless your using thermal compound you bought by the pound (see YouTube video by Linus Tech to understand this reference), then no, it's unlikely the quality of the compound.  If you didn't apply the correct amount then, that might be it, but way to broad to say for certian

Comment: Maybe you bought a tube of whatever, that is everything but thermal compound. If the cooling device doesn't get the heat away from the chip, then you have a bad connection

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for a processor to overheat even with correctly applied quality thermal compound if the environment is to hot (hot room and/or other devices generating heat in the case, or a fan not working, blocked cooling vent - eg used on a duvet or similar).

It could also happen if the motherboard is faulty (or crap, with bad PSU) and/or you are overvolting or over clocking the CPU (these are not so likely to happen in a laptop.